# div isnt shown when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using an admin panel for managment and im trying to jump between tables by hiding them and showing each only when a certain id is clicked.
it doesnt work, I hide the div but I cant show it back again... any suggestions where is the mistake in the syntax? already checked for double id's

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#userst").click(function(){
    $("#userstable").show();
});
});
</script>
<li>
            <i  id = "userst" class="clip-grid-6" ></i>
            <a href="#">Users </a>
</li>

<div id = "userstable" class="row"  style=" overflow:auto; display:none;>
 </div>
```

those are the rellevant lines of code.

Comment: This is definitely not all of the relevant code. Did you even test the snippet you gave above? It is lacking the css definition for your `i` element (without it, the element is width:0, height:0 because of lack of content). As written, this code will run, and if the `i` element has size, the click event will fire.

Comment: Your code is invalid.  You can't have space in id=" ", secondly you are missing a double quote after style=" ".  Thirdly, I don't believe you can write code in a script tag that is importing jquery

Comment: As an example, I have fixed your code check out this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJegZB

Comment: I had this code running well before I inserted the display none element.

Comment: Does "userstable" have body to show? Give it a width and a height and background color to make sure. Or some text... something

Answer (score 0):

Forgot a double quote around style attribute, and add content for div. Also updated Javascript code.

**HTML**

Try to change from

```
<div id = "userstable" class="row"  style=" overflow:auto; display:none;>
```

to

```
<div id = "userstable" class="row"  style=" overflow:auto; display:none;">
```

**JS**

```
$("#userst").parent().find("a").click(function(){
    $("#userstable").show();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2a8cmy6v/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has some flaws. First the id "userst" has no body. You are targeting the i-tag (italic), which you close before creating the anchor link.
Second you forgot to close the style attribute list in div with id "userstable"

```
<li>
   <i id="userst" class="clip-grid-6" ><a href="#">Users</a></i>
</li>
```

To make the anchor tag not fire with jQuery, you would need to add event.preventDefault and have the event as argument in the function.

```
$("#userst").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#userstable").show();
});
```